# Django: Creating editable default values for model instance based on foreignkey existance

Tags: python, django, database, models

I'm playing around in Django, and wondering if there is a way to loop through instances of two different models I have created?

```
/ models.py:

class Tran(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

 class DocLink(models.Model):
    trann = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    t_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    t_display = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    p_display = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    p_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.link
```

What I want to do:

Look through each of the Tran instances and create a default value for the links/displays in the DocLink table instead of doing it manually.

Is there anyway I can be pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set links/displays default value in DocLink instance based on trann field you can override model's save method.

For example following code shows how to set t_link if it doesn't have a value:

```
class DocLink(models.Model):
    trann = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    t_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    t_display = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    p_display = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    p_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.link

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.t_link:
            pass # TODO set self.t_link based on trann

        super(DocLink, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also you can change model's trann field to:

```
trann = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, related_name="doclinks")
```

And then access to all DocLinks of a Tran with:

```
# t is an instance of Tran class

t.doclinks.all()
```

So you can loop through this list and do what you want.

Comment: Hm ok that makes sense, but the part that I'm a little confused about, how would I set each of the t_links and p_links to, let's say "google.com" for example?

Comment: Also, I have instances of the Tran class created in my database that I manually inputted. Because the doclink's instance existence relies heavily upon the existence of the the Tran instances, will the code allow me to create instances of the doclinks class in relation to the matching tran instance? The purpose of the doclink class is to just add links containing documentation of the instances created by the tran class. I hope I expressed that well!

Comment: @adropofilm if your links are static, for example always you want to set them to "google.com" you must use default keyword. (t_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="google.co"). but if not, instead of "pass" in above code you must set them with desired conditions. if self.trann.name=="foo": self.t_links = "google.com"

Comment: @adropofilm about your second comment I didn't get the point. in this code it's not important that you manualy created instances of Tran or not only instances of DocLink are important. When you use django save() method on a DocLink instances before storing it in database(with super(DocLink, self).save(*args, **kwargs)) you can change values that you want to change. I don't know it's answer of you comment or not, let me know if it was Irrelevant.